# Javascript replace() using html entities not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following script, which successfully replaces < and > with the code indicated below. The idea here is that a user would put  into the text box if they want "Bold me" to appear bolded on their blog.

```
$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&lt;', '<span class="bold">'));
});

$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&gt;', '</span>'));
});
```

The problem comes with other html entities. I'm going to simply my example. I want to replace the [ html entity with a paragraph tag, but none of the lines in this script work. I've tried documenting each code that related to the '[' character.

```
$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&#x0005B;', '<p>'));
});

$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&lbrack;', '<p>'));
});

$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&lsqb;', '<p>'));
});

$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(string.replace('&lbrack;', '<p>'));
});
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: LOL! This is the correct answer. I am not a smart man.

Comment: Feel free to document this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @json done. I've turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `'['` is not a [character entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) so it is not encoded. Just pass it directly to `replace`:

```
string.replace('[' , '<p>')
```

Comment: I've just discovered that only the first instance of [ is replaced on the page. Any thoughts as to why? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonHoward That's how [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) work. If you want to replace all insantces, you'll have to use a regex with the global modifier `g`: `replace(/\[/g, '<p>')`, or use `split`/`join`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonHoward ... more on that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/9867451). And you're welcome!